# Add a class to a group of elements in Pandoc markdown?

Tags: html, pandoc

I use Pandoc to create content for my website.

For example, I have the following content on a page:

```
# About me

Some text.

## My hobbies

### Hiking

Some text about hiking.

### Dancing

Some text about dancing.

### Other

Some text about other.

## Why I love Pandoc

Some more text.
```

Pandoc parses this for me and outputs nice HTML.

But I want to post-process this HTML further, for example I want the hobbies part to become an accordion.

For this I'd like it to be in its own container, e.g. a `<div class="accordion">`. Is this possible somehow?

**Update**

By attaching a class to the specific heading, I can achieve something close to what I need:

```
## My hobbies {.accordion}

...
```

Now I can target everything using CSS like this (code not tested):

```
h2.accordion ~ *:not(h1, h2) {
  color: red;
}
```

This assumes that the everything up to the next heading on the same (or higher) level belongs to the carousel.

This can be of help. I don't know though whether it fits all my requirements, but it's a start.

Answer (score 5):

Sure, markdown supports [raw HTML](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#raw-html) and [native divs](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-native_divs):

```
## My hobbies

<div class="hobbies">
### Hiking
Some text about hiking.
</div>
```

And since pandoc 2.0 even [`fenced_divs`](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-fenced_divs):

```
## My hobbies

::: hobbies
### Hiking
Some text about hiking.
:::
```

Comment: Hmm, as I export my content also to other formats (e.g. Word) using Pandoc, I'd rather have a cross-format-compatible solution. Adding generic HTML doesn't seem right to me. I added some more info to my question with a first idea on how to approach my requirement with the limited feature set of Pandoc.

Comment: The `div` is accessible in pandoc filters as well.... anyway, you don't state in your question how the accordion would look in word etc and what "your requirements" are...

Comment: The accordion should just be ignored in Word and other formats. Only on the website I want to enhance my rich text. I still think that adding HTML just doesn't feel right, as a default editor who uses Markdown may not know about HTML.

Comment: there's actually an issue to replace the HTML div syntax in markdown... https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/168 will be resolved eventually...

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem ;)